# How to print the line number for the search text in linux

Tags: linux, search, command, git-bash

I am trying to search for a particular text in a file and want to print all the matching cases along with their line number in git bash.

Answer (score 0):

grep -nr "`text to be searched`" `file path`

For Example: 
If you want to search for a word suppose "ABC" in file "/src/test/java/com/company/version/base/sample.txt" then the command will be:

*grep -nr "ABC" src/test/java/com/company/version/base/sample.txt*
15: private final String ABC;

Here, "15" is the line number at which an ABC variable is declared.